# Unable to add button inside div tag

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to add a button over my social link div tags, but no matter what I do, the button is not displayed onto of the div tag.

[image]

As you can see, the button is inside the parent div tag, but it is displayed too far down. How can I move it to be inside the div tag.

Here is my code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <style>
        
    html,body,#container {
        background-color: rgb(230,230,230);
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    
    #container {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    #spaceBox {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 800px;
        height: 30px;
        top:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px;
        margin: auto;
        border-radius: 25px;
    }
    
    #socialLinksContainerBox {
        background-color: white;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 800px;
        height: 125px;
        top:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px;
        margin: auto;
        border-radius: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        overflow:hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    #socialLinksMiniBox {
        background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
        width: calc(100% / 7);  
        height: 43%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;   
        text-align:center;
        margin:2%;    
        padding:20px;
        border-radius: 25px;
    }
    
    #socialLogo {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
    }
    
    #socialLabel {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
        bottom: 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #socialButtonOne {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        top:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px;
        z-index: 100;
        display: block;
    }
    
    </style>
    
    <head>
      <title>MyCircle</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="spaceBox"></div>
        <div id="socialLinksContainerBox">
            <div id="socialLinksMiniBox">
                <img id="socialLogo" src="https://my-circle.io/OtherFiles/SocialLogos/instagram.png">
                <p id="socialLabel">Instagram</p>
                <button id="socialButtonOne" type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
            </div>
            <div id="socialLinksMiniBox">
                <img id="socialLogo" src="https://my-circle.io/OtherFiles/SocialLogos/youtube.png">
                <p id="socialLabel">YouTube</p>
            </div>
            <div id="socialLinksMiniBox">
                <img id="socialLogo" src="https://my-circle.io/OtherFiles/SocialLogos/x.png">
                <p id="socialLabel">X</p>
            </div>
            <div id="socialLinksMiniBox">
                <img id="socialLogo" src="https://my-circle.io/OtherFiles/SocialLogos/tiktok.png">
                <p id="socialLabel">TikTok</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's using relative positioning, but not in any meaningful way.  It's basically part of the flow of the other elements in that same `<div>`, and it's "below" them and overflowing below the `<div>`.

You can change the `<div>` to use relative positioning, then change the button to use absolute positioning therein:

```css
html,body,#container {
    background-color: rgb(230,230,230);
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
}

#spaceBox {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 30px;
    top:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

#socialLinksContainerBox {
    background-color: white;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 125px;
    top:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#socialLinksMiniBox {
    background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
    width: calc(100% / 7);  
    height: 43%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;   
    text-align:center;
    margin:2%;    
    padding:20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    position: relative; /* <--- here */
}

#socialLogo {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

#socialLabel {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
    bottom: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

#socialButtonOne {
    position: absolute; /* <--- and here */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    top:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px;
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="spaceBox"></div>
    <div id="socialLinksContainerBox">
        <div id="socialLinksMiniBox">
            <img id="socialLogo" src="https://my-circle.io/OtherFiles/SocialLogos/instagram.png">
            <p id="socialLabel">Instagram</p>
            <button id="socialButtonOne" type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
        </div>
        <div id="socialLinksMiniBox">
            <img id="socialLogo" src="https://my-circle.io/OtherFiles/SocialLogos/youtube.png">
            <p id="socialLabel">YouTube</p>
        </div>
        <div id="socialLinksMiniBox">
            <img id="socialLogo" src="https://my-circle.io/OtherFiles/SocialLogos/x.png">
            <p id="socialLabel">X</p>
        </div>
        <div id="socialLinksMiniBox">
            <img id="socialLogo" src="https://my-circle.io/OtherFiles/SocialLogos/tiktok.png">
            <p id="socialLabel">TikTok</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, that works perfectly.